# Clarification about the ϵ -net argument

Tags: pr.probability, gn.general-topology, st.statistics, machine-learning

I have been reading the paper [Do GANs learn the distribution? Some theory and empirics](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=BJehNfW0-).

In Corollary D.1, they reference the paper [Generalization and Equilibrium in Generative Adversarial Nets](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.00573.pdf) which in Theorem B.2 constructs an ϵ-net to get an upper bound for an expectation.

I have little background in topology (CS grad student) so I'm not sure what the authors mean when they say they use "standard constructions" to obtain $\log |X | ≤ O(p\ \log(LL_\phi p/\epsilon))$ (in theorem B.2).

I'm also unsure as to where they get the probability $1 − \exp(−p)$ required for the proof from. Could someone more knowledgeable clear this up for me? Also a reference for these sorts of things would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.